# How to generate a token string in a custom keycloak extension?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I’m pretty new to Keycloak development and at the moment I’m trying to develop some demo extensions to learn how SPI’s an stuff like that work in Keycloak.

**My Question is: Is there a util- or helper-class which I can use to generate an secure token string in my extension code (pretty much the same as an oauth access or refresh token string)?**

I was not able to find something In the Keycloak code, but maybe there is something like that. I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is an easy solution in keycloak i can use.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here ist the answer from the mailing list: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2018-January/010340.html

> Keycloak provides action tokens that permits its bearer to perform some
>   actions, e. g. to reset a password or validate e-mail address.
>
> Perhaps you could have a look at the action tokens SPI:
>   http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_development/topics/action-token-spi.html
>
> Keycloaks OIDC Tokens (AccessToken, RefreshToken, IDToken) are generated
>   within `org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.TokenManager` and exposed
>   via the `org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint`. Tokens can be
>   verified via the `org.keycloak.RSATokenVerifier`.